# TFS 2010 public workspace: checkins belong always to owner of workspace

Tags: tfs, workspace

Using a public workspace on one machine for several users works quite good.

BUT; every checkout/checkin belongs to the user who owns the workspace and
declared it as public and not to the user, who is authenticated on TFS server.
Though I found the description *"The checkins will still be attributed to the person checking them in."* in [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/11/08/tfs2010-public-workspaces.aspx)

So I have no reference, which users made which changes, working with the public workspace.

If this is "by design" in TFS 2010, does anybody know if this has been changed in TFS 2013/2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design and will not be changed in future versions. It is not the purpose of Public Workspaces to allow multiple people to share a workspace on the same machine constantly.

The system does maintain an "authorized as" that has the user that actually did the checkin, however they are doing it "on behalf of" the workspace owner.

Comment: It is possible however to change the owner of the public workspace. The public workspace must not have pending changes, then the owner field can be edited. Works for me.